# Cookie in WebView2 WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, cookies, token, webview2

How we can store some value in cookie or any storage like session/local and retrieve the same in `WebView2` in `WPF`.

I tried How do I set the cookie on the `WebView2` control using the `CoreWebView2CookieManager`

I am applying below on page initialize -

```
string uri = @"http://localhost:8080"; 
var cookie = WebView
    .CoreWebView2
    .CookieManager
    .CreateCookie("Token", "XJKDKD", ".com", null);
cookie.IsHttpOnly = true;
cookie.IsSecure = true;
WebView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(cookie);
WebView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(uri);
```

But facing below issue

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.WebView2.CoreWebView2.get
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your webview2 is initialized properly.

```
// should be called from Window Constructor after InitializeComponent()
// `async void` signature is required for environment init
async void InitializeAsync()
{
   
    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
   
   // you might need this event for something    
   webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
   
   // set the initial URL
   webView.Source = new Uri("https://yourwebsite.here");
}
```

**Api Doc**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1370.28

Comment: Thanks, by doing above it is setting cookie under application tab. Could you please let me know how we can get it on react js side. I tired both import Cookies from "js-cookie";
and
import cookie from 'react-cookie' but it is showing undefined.

Comment: IMO that could be separate part in new post. If you are able to set cookies then first try opening dev-tools of WebView2 and see if cookies are set there or not.